# subsetting xts column by date vector

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I'm trying to assign a column to a data.frame from another xts:

```
dts = c(today() - 2, today() - 1, today())
a = data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3))
b = data.frame(v = c(.5, .25, 1), date = dts)
b = rbind(b, b)

a = xts(a, order.by = dts)

b$a = coredata(a$a[b$date])
```

This returns:

```
     v       date a
1 0.50 2020-07-06 1
2 0.25 2020-07-07 1
3 1.00 2020-07-08 2
4 0.50 2020-07-06 2
5 0.25 2020-07-07 3
6 1.00 2020-07-08 3
```

If I look at the order of column 'a' it doesn't follow what I would expect. What do I have to change in order for column 'a' to follow the date column (should be 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)

Answer (score 2):

`xts` objects are ordered automatically

```
a = xts(a, order.by = dts)
```

For instance, I add something at the end of a with `rbind` but it is ordering automatically and it appears at the beggining :

```
rbind(a, a[1])
           a
2020-07-06 1
2020-07-06 1
2020-07-07 2
2020-07-08 3
```

Is is exactly what it is done in your example.

One solution is to stop using `xts` object for this operation :

```
b$a = as.numeric(a)[match(b$date, date(a))]
b
     v       date a
1 0.50 2020-07-06 1
2 0.25 2020-07-07 2
3 1.00 2020-07-08 3
4 0.50 2020-07-06 1
5 0.25 2020-07-07 2
6 1.00 2020-07-08 3
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661145/rbind-with-xts-how-to-stack-without-sorting-by-index-date) for the same problem.